# EC2 deploy Sails JS production configurations (not included in git)

Tags: node.js, sails.js, devops

I want a deploy a Sails JS app on EC2. How can i create a production configuration (which consists sensitive data, so not included in git).

What is the best practice to create production configurations. Which should also work in case of auto scaling.

If i create `.sailsrc` file manually then it won't work in case of auto scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking you need a process manager. The most used one for node apps is **PM2** visit : http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/ for more info.

## Sails configuration

In Sails you can setup different environments for your application.
visit : https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/deployment

You can setup your sensitive information (API Keys and such) as environment variables.
This an example from my project: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg1dy.jpg

For environment variables you can use dotenv visit: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv .Basically you create a .env file in your root directory where you declare your sensitive keys, **don't forget to add it to .gitignore file**, now you just need to require it early on and you should be set !

## How i do it

In addition to .env file i use **PM2** Process file.

see : http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/

This is my ecosystem.config.js file :

`module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name        : "Sails App",
    script      : "./app.js",
    env: {
      "NODE_ENV": "development",
    },
    env_production : {
       "NODE_ENV": "production",
       "REDIS_HOST": "10.13.xx.xx",
       "REDIS_PORT": "67xx"
    }
  }]
}`

**Place it in the root of your app and don't forget to add it to your .gitignore**

Then just run `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production --update-env`

Hope this helps !

Comment: In case of single ec2 instance i can create ecosystem.config.js manually, but how does it work in auto scaling (multiple ec2 instances). Do i need to create an AMI of ec2 instance after setting all configurations & use that AMI for auto scaling?

Comment: That would work you just need to daemonize the PM2 process ! and be careful with you bootstrap.js logic if you are going to use multiple instances.